# Get text from <a> element?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to get the school name, "Perkins College..." from this [link](http://www.geteducated.com/profiles/show/online-degrees/stephen-f-austin-state-university/perkins-college-of-education-undergraduate/395/5401/undergraduate-certificate-in-hospitality-administration) using beautifulSoup.

The code I use returns nothing.

```
school = soup.find('a','profiles-show-school-name-sm-link')
print 'school: ', school
print 'school.text: ', school.text
```

output:

```
school:  <a class="profiles-show-school-name-sm-link" href="/profiles/show/online-degrees/stephen-f-austin-state-university/perkins-college-of-education-undergraduate/395/5401">
<img border="0" src="/images/profiles/243x60/4613/degrees/undergraduate-certificate-in-hospitality-administration.png"/>
</a>
school.text:
```

Suggestions for a BeautifulSoup implementation to extract school name (not URL)? Thx!

Comment: Are you looking for a beautifulsoup implementation to extract the school name? If you're trying to get the href, I believe school['href'] will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
school = soup.find('a','profiles-show-school-name-sm-link')
url = school['href']
```

Assuming the school is always in the same spot in the url:

```
for i in range(5):
   url = url[url.find("/")+1:]
schoolname = url[:url.find("/")]
print " ".join(schoolname.split("-")).title()
```

Yields:

```
Perkins College Of Education Undergraduate
```

Getting the University

```
for i in range(4):
   url = url[url.find("/")+1:]
university= url[:url.find("/")]
print " ".join(university.split("-")).title()
```

Yields:

```
Stephen F Austin State University
```

Comment: This actually gets the school within the university. How would you get the university after the <br>? Thx!

Comment: If you go to this url: http://www.geteducated.com/profiles/show/online-degrees/stephen-f-austin-state-university/perkins-college-of-education-undergraduate/395/5401/undergraduate-certificate-in-hospitality-administration

Comment: And inspect element on "stephen f austin university" just above the address, then you will see this occurs after a br

Comment: The code in the answer returns only the first part, and I'm trying to get the second part as well, which is the university name.

Comment: The way the code above is accomplishing this is parsing the url in the 'href' given by soup.find('a','profiles-show-school-name-sm-link'). It doesn't use the url string. I don't use beautiful soup, but I imagine you can get the string by school.string. If you want the university from the href, you can simply change the range to 4 in the for loop.